# I'm typing out a Data Mapping table and want to see if I am correct

Tags: string, varchar, data-mapping

I have a data mapping table and these are the examples I have I just want to ensure I am correct.
The format is the example I have --> what my answer is. CTMC --> String, 0000125006 --> String, T1927 --> VARCHAR, UA --> String. Am I correct in my thinking? Anything that might fit a little better instead of VARCHAR for T1927? Thank you in advance.